# Input data - recognition of human actions in videos using TFLearn

Tags: video, tensorflow, dataset, hdf5, tflearn

it's my first question here, I'm starting to work with Tflearn and I'm having a problem. I have a dataset in .AVI format videos, I first divided them into several .PNG photos (each frame of the video), and then I was thinking how I could work with them in TFLearn. Looking at the documentation of the site I found a way, I would like to know if this is the most appropriate, and another doubt is, what basically are the X and Y?

I chose the HDF5 Image Dataset input mode, and here is my txt file.

```
/home/messias/TensorFlow/Dataset/Weizmann/abaixado/daria_bend/daria_bend_001.png 1
/home/messias/TensorFlow/Dataset/Weizmann/abaixado/daria_bend/daria_bend_002.png 1
/home/messias/TensorFlow/Dataset/Weizmann/abaixado/daria_bend/daria_bend_003.png 1
/home/messias/TensorFlow/Dataset/Weizmann/abaixado/daria_bend/daria_bend_004.png 1
/home/messias/TensorFlow/Dataset/Weizmann/abaixado/daria_bend/daria_bend_005.png 1
```

Only a part of it as an example

And here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import h5py
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_3d, max_pool_3d
from tflearn.data_utils import build_hdf5_image_dataset
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

#Carregar o txt do dataset
dataset_file_train = 'Training.txt'
dataset_file_test = 'Test.txt'

#Cria um dataset HDF5
build_hdf5_image_dataset(dataset_file_train, image_shape=(180, 144), mode='file', output_path='dataset_train.h5', categorical_labels=True, normalize=True)
build_hdf5_image_dataset(dataset_file_test, image_shape=(180, 144), mode='file', output_path='dataset_test.h5', categorical_labels=True, normalize=True)

# Load HDF5 dataset
h5f_train = h5py.File('dataset_train.h5', 'r')
X = h5f_train['X']
Y = h5f_train['Y']
h5f_test = h5py.File('dataset_test.h5', 'r')
testX = h5f_test['X']
testY = h5f_test['Y']
```

I would like to know, with this is it possible to compare frames ranges? I also tried to implement a 3D convolutional neural network but for now I only got this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 144, 180, 3) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 10, 180, 144, 3)'
```

Here's my code:

```
# Criando a rede neural convolucional 3D
network = input_data(shape=[None, 10, 180, 144, 3])
network = conv_3d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_3d(network, 2)
network = conv_3d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_3d(network, 2)
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.001)

# Treinamento
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1, validation_set=(testX, testY), snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='Primeira_CNN')
```

I have already tried several solutions found here of type "reshape", but nothing works, which makes me wonder if my method of data entry is correct. If anyone can comment on all the architecture I would greatly appreciate it!

Obs: Sorry for the bad English, I translated by google translator.